# how to make a video created by FFMPEG using downloaded images, VLC media player compatible

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc

I am making a mp4 video while using this command from downloaded jpegs, everything is working fine but the video is not being played in VLC but in Media Player, default one of Ubuntu.

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 6 -i #{path}%d.jpg -i #{evercam_logo} -filter_complex '[1]scale=iw/2:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10' -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -bufsize 1000k #{path}#{id}.mp4
```

I have tried multiple formats but the results are same. what Am I missing here? any help would be wonderful thank you.

my FFMPEG version:

```
ffmpeg version N-95730-ga7245adee3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      56. 35.101 / 56. 35.101
  libavcodec     58. 62.100 / 58. 62.100
  libavformat    58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 66.100 /  7. 66.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

FFMPEG is being compiled with Nvidia Graphics.

UPDATE:
this is the output of my full command

```
root@Ubuntu-1704-zesty-64-minimal:~# ffmpeg -y -framerate 6 -i /storage/apache-j8h3/%d.jpg -i /opt/evercam_media/lib/evercam_media-1.0.1583305674/priv/static/images/evercam-logo-white.png -filter_complex '[1]scale=iw/2:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10,format=yuv420p' -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -bufsize 1000k videotest.mp4
ffmpeg version N-95730-ga7245adee3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      56. 35.101 / 56. 35.101
  libavcodec     58. 62.100 / 58. 62.100
  libavformat    58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 66.100 /  7. 66.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
Input #0, image2, from '/storage/apache-j8h3/%d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:09.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 704x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], 6 fps, 6 tbr, 6 tbn, 6 tbc
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/opt/evercam_media/lib/evercam_media-1.0.1583305674/priv/static/images/evercam-logo-white.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 200x200 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale
  format -> Stream #0:0 (h264_nvenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 0x555f0a16ba80] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[swscaler @ 0x555f0a36ff80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, mp4, to 'videotest.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 704x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], q=-1--1, 2000 kb/s, 6 fps, 12288 tbn, 6 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.62.100 h264_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/2000000 buffer size: 1000000 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=   57 fps=0.0 q=20.0 Lsize=    2332kB time=00:00:09.33 bitrate=2046.8kbits/s speed=19.3x    
video:2331kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.045540%
```

and this is the output of a command with `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

```
root@Ubuntu-1704-zesty-64-minimal:~# ffmpeg -y -framerate 6 -i /storage/apache-j8h3/%d.jpg -i /opt/evercam_media/lib/evercam_media-1.0.1583305674/priv/static/images/evercam-logo-white.png -filter_complex '[1]scale=iw/2:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10' -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -bufsize 1000k -pix_fmt yuv420p videotest.mp4
ffmpeg version N-95730-ga7245adee3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      56. 35.101 / 56. 35.101
  libavcodec     58. 62.100 / 58. 62.100
  libavformat    58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 66.100 /  7. 66.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
Input #0, image2, from '/storage/apache-j8h3/%d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:09.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 704x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], 6 fps, 6 tbr, 6 tbn, 6 tbc
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/opt/evercam_media/lib/evercam_media-1.0.1583305674/priv/static/images/evercam-logo-white.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 200x200 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (h264_nvenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 0x557669b1fb00] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[swscaler @ 0x557669d23bc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, mp4, to 'videotest.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 704x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], q=-1--1, 2000 kb/s, 6 fps, 12288 tbn, 6 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.62.100 h264_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/2000000 buffer size: 1000000 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=   57 fps=0.0 q=20.0 Lsize=    2332kB time=00:00:09.33 bitrate=2046.8kbits/s speed=19.8x    
video:2331kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.045540%
```

Comment: I believe this is your question answered:
https://superuser.com/questions/820134/why-cant-quicktime-play-a-movie-file-encoded-by-ffmpeg

Comment: I have tried `10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10,format=yuv420p'` this dont work

Comment: also if you see above command. I am already using `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Comment: Show the full log from your command. Otherwise we can only guess. What is your VLC version? Lazy guess is to try a higher `-framerate` value than 6, or add `-r` output option with higher value than 6.

Comment: @llogan I have updated the full command log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame rate is too low for some players. Increase `-framerate` value or add the `-r` option. Anything ≥8 should suffice. Example:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 6 -i /storage/apache-j8h3/%d.jpg -i /opt/evercam_media/lib/evercam_media-1.0.1583305674/priv/static/images/evercam-logo-white.png -filter_complex '[1]scale=iw/2:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10,format=yuv420p' -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -bufsize 1000k -r 12 videotest.mp4
```

In the case above with usage of `-r` then frames will be duplicated to convert from 6 fps to 12 fps, but it won't be noticeable by the viewer.

Comment: can you explain more about -r option?

Comment: also I have tested to create a clip with -r 12, it also increases the size of the file without -r it 2.8 mb and with -r its 3.7 mb